# Vapor Barrier possibly concealing leaks

Tags: ceiling, leak, moisture, vapor-barrier

Vapor barrier concealing leaks

Hey there! I could really use some advice on those that have plastic sheeting in their ceilings. We just moved into a 1970s socal home in June.

1. We have had numerous leaks since moving into our home. The first and second time it was water pouring out of our entry smoke detector & 3 nearby recessed lights on floor 1.
2. The third time it was an even larger amount of water pouring out of the same smoke detector, 6 recessed lights and the ceiling fan in the next room over. Probably about a bathtub worth of water.
3. We had maintenance come check. They cut open two holes about the size of paint stirrer stick. They found absolutely no evidence of a leak. Basically calling us crazy. However they did not cut open the plastic sheet lining the ceiling.
4. Is it possible that water be pooling in the plastic sheet and of leading to moisture/mold growth?

Some notable points:

-My husband, son, and I have been terribly sick with severe sinus infection like symptoms since we’ve moved here. We’ve all been treated with antibiotics & steroids to no avail.
-However my husband feels much better at work & my son’s nose stops running at school. Their symptoms return when they get back home.
-I on the other hand stay at home, and I’m the most sick out of my family. I actually spent 7 days in the hospital last month for meningitis of an unknown origin, possibly fungal. Within a week of returning home I was sick again.

-We live in military base housing. It’s privatized housing but federal property, so state law does not apply.The local health department cannot help us. We are not allowed to bring in an inspector or our maintenance contractor. There is no option for us to withhold the $3700 housing allowance that is our rent money. It goes directly from the military to the company. I have to convince their maintenance people to find the water intrusion and mold growth or we will be forced to stay in the home. If you Google liberty military housing mold issues, you will find that we are one of hundreds of families living in hazardous conditions.

Comment: Your local health department will come and do tests.  It seems enough to make your family sick now, but to keep living something needs to change soon.  Your health department should have big steel boots to make changes happen.

Comment: Of _course_ plastic holds water. What's the question, exactly? You know you need to fix the roof (or plumbing) leaks and you know you need to dry out your home and you know you need to test for mold and act according to the results. What else can we tell you?

Comment: You said you had "...maintenance come check."   If you live in a n apartment  and rent or you own a condo, this would be an ongoing situation until the source of leaks were found.  The management company has a responsibility to document work orders and the status. They also need to treat a situation with negative health conditions with an abundance of caution.   Next time document the leaks with video.

Comment: Yah -- the whole design is dodgy as @#$!@$!@$ with a full blown vapor barrier in the ceiling like that even

Comment: @crip659 Please cite the laws on which you base your comment. What will they test for exactly, and what specific criteria will they use to determine a problem on which they will take action? IANAL, but AFAIK, your comment, although certainly reasonable, is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: You've asked one actual question (possible for water to be pooling in plastic) to which the answer is obviously "yes". You've got a sentence fragment ending in a question mark, but really isn't a question. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] this to ask what you're really trying to get at, because it isn't particularly clear.

Comment: Ooof... Military housing. I feel for you. My son is Army and he and his wife have had nothing but problems without solutions for their on-post housing at to different posts. TBH, your best bet to avoid the mold issues is to get off post. I don't even think the post CO has enough pull to get the management company to do anything on your behalf. Also, thank you for your service! Even if it's your husband, the whole family pays the price.

Answer (score 1):

Plastic sheeting as a vapor barrier can absolutely conceal leaks. Last summer I worked on a project where we didn't know the extent of the leak until we peeled back the vapor barrier. From the inside, you couldn't tell anything was amiss. The entire wall was made of rot though. You could push your finger right through the wood.

As to the second part of your question, I won't speculate. Mold can cause health issues. If I was in your situation, I would be looking to move. That's as much as I will say.

Comment: Yeah if you are in a rental and you are all sick and sensitive to mold easier to move than have it properly fixed.  Proper fix can take a long time and be very involved if the person is even willing to put in the time.

Answer (score 0):

Rachel, I'm so sorry to learn of your situation.

Yes, vapor barriers can definitely conceal leaks.  Simply put, mold thrives on moisture and food.  Vapor barriers can help provide that needed moisture, and some building materials provide an excellent food source for mold growth.

Please carefully read the laws there: it is highly unlikely that your health department will do anything at all (despite a non-referenced claim in the comments to the contrary).

For your health, moving will most likely be required.  Given your family's level of illness since moving into this property, disposing/decontaminating all/most of your possessions will likely be warranted.  Just like the maintenance worker who basically called you crazy, people will likely call me crazy too for making these recommendations.  That's unfortunate, but simply a reflection of their lack of mycology education and often a result of them placing their financial interest (or ego) over your well-being.

The health effects from mold can be truly devastating and life-altering.  Given your experiences at this property, the sooner you get your family out, the better.  You likely have already concluded that the property owner does not prioritize your health or the maintenance of their property.

Given your geographic region, I believe the wet season is about to approach you.  If your family is suffering from the effects of mold due to problems with the property, it would be reasonable to expect your family's health problems to get substantially worse as the rainfall increases.

If you desire any recourse, you will likely need a good civil attorney, and that won't be easy or cheap.  If the landlord has insurance, you may eventually recoup your losses.  If they don't, it is unfortunately unlikely you will recoup most of your losses.